# AJAX call in Wordpress on submit

Tags: ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I never use wordpress so I'm totally lost ... I have a wordpress site that contains forms created with the "contact-form-7" plugin ... I would need to make an ajax call to send the form data to an external URLe when the user submit one of the forms on the site ... what should I do?

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  url: "external url",
  data: JSON.stringify({
          "env": "",
          "application": "",
          "operation": "",
          "token": "",
          "utente": "",
          "param": "",
       "data":{ DATA FROM FORM }
        }),
  dataType: 'json',
  },
  error: function(message) {
      
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'wpcf7_before_send_mail' filter to send the contact form7 submitted data to any website using CURL or wp_remote_post.

```
   add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail*', 'wpcf7_submite_data_to_3rdparty' );
    
    function wpcf7_submite_data_to_3rdparty( $contact_form ) {
        global $wpdb;
    
    if ( ! isset( $contact_form->posted_data ) && class_exists( 'WPCF7_Submission' ) ) {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    
        if ( $submission ) {
            $form_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        }
    } else {
        return '';
    }
    
    $body = array(        
        'name' => $form_data['name'],
        'email' => $form_data['email'],
        'comments' => $form_data['comments'],
    );
    
    $url = 'https://example.com';
    
    $params = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ),
        'body' => $body
    );
    
        $response = wp_remote_post( $url,  $params );
        
    }
```

For handling Jquery events you can use event listener.

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    console.log('mail sent OK');
    // Stuff
}, false );
```

wpcf7mailsent Fires when an Ajax form submission has completed successfully, and mail has been sent.
wpcf7submit Fires when an Ajax form submission has completed successfully, regardless of other incidents.

Comment: Why are you calling `$wpdb?`  Also, why `return $contact_form` on about line 12?  Neither of these seem necessary.  Since this is a hook and not a filter, you can just `return` to exit.  So you should be using `add_action` and not `add_filter`